# Is there a way to embed or include a database file into an html file? If not is there another way I could do something similar?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a website for an assignment. In this assignment, I have to include examples of some of my work and I want to include a database I made in Microsoft Access, is there anyway I could do this? It preferably has to be in html. The database is just a table, a form and a report.

Comment: What's in this database?  Just tabular data?  How much data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTML can't to connect to database alone, you should to use other tecnology together to this be possible, a better way to do it in a web system is to connect through a API, if not know about, google it, have a lot of documentation and tutorial to make modern restful API, for your case that is using microsoft access I found this Microsoft tutorial maybe can help you.

-> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308459/how-to-connect-an-html-page-to-a-microsoft-access-database